# GPIO Error on Raspberry Pi when following Adafruit Tutorial

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Having a very strange issue on my Raspberry Pi when following this tutorial...

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/usage

When I run the example script, I'm getting the below error:

```
pi@thethingbox ~/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/examples $ sudo python char_lcd_plate.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "char_lcd_plate.py", line 6, in <module>
    import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py",line 23, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Adafruit_GPIO
```

It was working fine. But when I rebooted I was forced to run fsck - now it's throwing the above error :-(

I've tried deleting the directory and starting again but I get the same issue.

Comment: If it helps to know, I'm running thingbox on my Pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library was probably corrupted when you rebooted. Just run the command below from the `Adafruit_Python_CharLCD` directory and you should be fine.

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: You could try installing the library directly from its repo https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO