# Troubleshooting Adafruit library issues on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adafruit

I tried to write a script that would output the dht 11 sensor data to a `.txt` file.
I reviewed the [standard examples](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2017/09/dht11-temperature-and-humidity-sensor-raspberry-pi/) given for the Adafruit library.

My code:

```
import time
import Adafruit_DHT


# infinite while loop

while True:

    sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11
    pin = 4

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

    if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
        print('Temp={0:0.1f}*  Humidity{1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature,humidity))
    else:
        print('Failed to get reading. Try again!')

    time.sleep(5)
```

When I run it with Thonny IDE, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/Sensor1/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/simpletest2loop.py", line 5, in <module>
import Adafruit_DHT
ImportError: No module named 'Adafruit_DHT'
```

I'm able to read the sensor from terminal using the command:

```
sudo ./AdafruitDHT.py 11 4
```

with another script listed in: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-measure-humidity-temperature-dht11-dht22/

I did some research, but I can't figure it out, I kindly ask if someone can help me to troubleshoot this.

**Research:**

- [importing dht11 Adafruit python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630060/importing-dht11-adafruit-python)
- [DHT11 Adafruit Library: Is this parameter necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995195/dht11-adafruit-library-is-this-parameter-necessary)
- [Trouble installing Adafruit's DHT11 Python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864254/trouble-installing-adafruits-dht11-python-library)
- I tried moving the file, but still doesn't work

## - [GPIO Error on Raspberry Pi when following Adafruit Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107770/gpio-error-on-raspberry-pi-when-following-adafruit-tutorial)

pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/Sensor1/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples $ ls -altr
    total 28

```
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 2035 Jul  5 15:28 simpletest.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi 5715 Jul  5 15:28 google_spreadsheet.py
drwxr-xr-x 10 pi pi 4096 Jul  5 15:28 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi 2340 Jul  6 13:19 AdafruitDHT.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi 4096 Jul 13 14:08 .
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi pi 1037 Jul 13 14:19 simpletest2loop.py <code>
```

Seems they are under same user and group. Do i have to copy the library to some folder?

Comment: So the root user can import the module, but you cannot within your IDE. I'd have to guess that you either installed the module only for the root user, or that you and the root user have different Python setups and/or environment variables.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the update. I checked seems they are under same user and group

Comment: AdafruitDHT.py != Adafruit_DHT.py, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble finding Python modules, the best way to sort it out is check:

- a) where Python is looking, and
- b) where your modules are.

So, if you want to check where Python is looking you could run this:

```
python3 -c "import sys; print(','.join(sys.path))"
```

**Sample Output**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.14.3_1/libexec/nose/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Then make sure your modules are in one of those places, or add to your `PYTHONPATH` so that it includes the location where you have installed your modules.

---

If you are running scripts as `root`, you should also run the code above as `root`.